# Using an Associative Array to Print Values Matching User Input

Tags: php

I have a small program I am trying to complete for class that requires me to take a user input, find the match in an array and then print the value if the values key matches the user input.

I have tried a few different things but the most common logical error I am getting is inputting one of the keys returns "DoReMiFaSoLaTi" with the current iteration (shown below).

Another issue I encounter is when I add an else block (echoing a "not here" error) to the if statement nested inside the foreach, it returns DoNotHereReNotHere etc.

This was classwork, so I have also tried in class regular for statements as well. Those did not work as intended.

I'm banging my head on the wall trying to figure out where the logic is wrong, so any help is very much appreciated. Thanks!

```
   <?php
$scale = array(
    "A" => "Do",
    "B" => "Re",
    "C" => 'Mi',
    "D" => 'Fa',
    "E" => 'So',
    "F" => 'La',
    "G" => 'Ti'
);

$query = isset($_POST['notes']);

if ($query != null)
{
    foreach ($scale as $key => $sound)
    {
        if ($query == $key)  
        {
            echo $sound;
        }
    }
}


?>

<form action="MusicalScale.php" method="post">

<label>Enter in a music note</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="notes"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `isset` you check if the variable is set. It's not there to declare a variable. Something like this will work:

```
if (isset($_POST['notes']))
{
    $query = $_POST['notes'];

    foreach ($scale as $key => $sound)
    {
        if ($query == $key)  
        {
            echo $sound;
            break;
        }
        else 
        {
            echo "There is no match!";
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess the point of the assignment was to have us use foreach? Not really sure, but the teacher made a point to mention it when the class was coming up with code for the exercise. I appreciate your help, this makes things a lot clearer. If I were to want to implement a return error when the user does not input a matching key, where would I put it? Adding an else block to the nested if in the foreach still results in "notherenothere" (iterating through the length of the array outputting nothere). Thanks again for any additional response!

Comment: I've update my answer. OK, the reason for using the foreach is, if someone inputs a value that does not match. Therefore you have to use an `if-else-statement` in the foreach.

Comment: Right on, I understand that bit. The problem is using this particular code results in the echo saying "There is no match!There is no match!There is no match!There is no match!There is no match!There is no match!There is no match!" which is what I was trying to avoid.

Comment: Haha, well, the only issue there is that "There is no match!" displays at the start of the program! No worries though, you got the more important part and the rest was just trying to be thorough. I'll do some more personal research and see if I can find a solution that works. Thanks again for all the effort!

Comment: Sorry, a little bit tired. NOW it should work! You have to use `break`.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <?php
$scale = array(
"A" => "Do",
"B" => "Re",
"C" => 'Mi',
"D" => 'Fa',
"E" => 'So',
"F" => 'La',
"G" => 'Ti'
);


if (isset($_POST['notes']))
 {
   $query=$_POST['notes'];
   foreach ($scale as $key => $sound)
   {
    if ($query == $key)  
    {
        echo $sound;
    }
    }
    }


 ?>

<form action="MusicalScale.php" method="post">

<label>Enter in a music note</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text"    name="notes"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

Comment: it should work now...  "isset ( )" - this method returns boolean value

Comment: It does properly respond to input, but I'm getting an undefined variable error on line 17 (if ($query != null)) and I still cannot set up an else block to show user error. Any idea on how to avoid the error? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You could also do it  like this without the loop.

```
$scale = array(
    "A" => "Do",
    "B" => "Re",
    "C" => 'Mi',
    "D" => 'Fa',
    "E" => 'So',
    "F" => 'La',
    "G" => 'Ti'
);

if(!empty($_POST['notes'])){

    if(!empty($scale[$_POST['notes']])){
        echo $scale[$_POST['notes']];
    }else{
        echo "Not here!";
    }

}
```